# how to increase datatable's name number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I know, how to increase integer, string by for statement

but I want know how to change the name by 'for ~next' statement.
For example,

```
    Dim row_sort1 As DataTable = rows1.CopyToDataTable
    Dim row_sort2 As DataTable = rows2.CopyToDataTable
    Dim row_sort3 As DataTable = rows3.CopyToDataTable
    Dim row_sort4 As DataTable = rows4.CopyToDataTable
    Dim row_sort5 As DataTable = rows5.CopyToDataTable
    Dim row_sort6 As DataTable = rows6.CopyToDataTable
    Dim row_sort7 As DataTable = rows7.CopyToDataTable
```

I had coding like this,, bad cording So I want change by 'for ~next' statement.
I want increase the  datatable name's number (1~7)
 how can reflect in this coding. I want fix my coding more simple and useful.

I need your help 
thank you

Comment: I think what you are looking for is arrays.

Comment: better to use array or list instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a Collection of Rows which is your master where you want to copy from.

I have a similiar approach like OSKM. Better use a list collection than an array.
To access tables afterwards in the collection you can use Linq.

```
' Given master rowcollection
Dim masterRow As EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)

' Empty table collection
Dim tableList As New List(Of DataTable)

For t As Integer = 0 To 6

    ' copy Master to a new table
    Dim newTable As DataTable = masterRow.CopyToDataTable()

    ' give the new table a name
    newTable.TableName = "Table" & t.ToString

    ' Add new table to collection
    tableList.Add(newTable)
Next

' Access a certain table (i.e. Table5) using Linq
Dim table5 As DataTable = tableList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.TableName = "Table5")
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correct the following might help.

```
    'Note your datatables will be named Datatable0 to Datatable6
    Dim DTs(6) As DataTable
    For i = 0 To 6
        DTs(i) = New DataTable
        DTs(i).TableName = "Datatable" & i
    Next
```

There is probably better ways but this will work!